# Changing Mac System Proxy Settings In Command Line Tool Application

Tags: objective-c, macos, proxy, command-line-tool

Is it possible to change proxy settings ( like what `networksetup` does ) in a command line tool app ? I mean I want to write a `command line tool` that can change network and proxy settings in mac.

If yes, Can anybody provide any source that I can go and search for starting points and learn about it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `NSTask` to run networksetup with desired arguments. In order to do that you must include AppKit framework to your application. (But please note that you need root privilege to use networksetup in order to change proxy settings)